# Xamarin Studio Crash when opening/creating a project

Tags: xamarin-studio

I want to try on Xamarin Studio on Mac. However, when I open/create a project (no matter iPhone/Android). The Studio crashed as shown in the image (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OImOA.png) to view image). I have re-installed it but the error still the same. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the best option for you is to go on Xamarin's Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/
And create an issue with the content of your crash message. I'm sure they will quickly reply.

Comment: I agree about this. Or you could at least post whole error message into something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and share it.